of and about in adjectives
I have studied the using of prepositions with adjective.When i looked the examples and explanations I saw the of and about in using telling of our feelings. and i was little bit confused because which adjectives showing our feelings have to use with of or about.
For example:
I am angry about your decisions (Why isn't ''I am angry of your decisions'')
She is scared of flying (Why isn't ''She is scared about flying)
I am nervous about driving again after the accident ((Why can't we say ''I am nervous of driving again after the accident)
You should be proud of your achievements!(Why can't we say ''You should be proud about your achievements)

Because the prepositions have different meanings and some can pair with a particular adjective and others cannot. They're not like 12mm hex nuts, where one is like all others.

You can say "I am nervous of [something]" - of is usually used with adjectives relating to fear, like scared, frightened and fearful.

There aren't really general rules that can be used to answer "why" questions like this. You just have to learn which combinations are idiomatic from experience.

What does, "I saw the of and about in using telling of our feelings," mean? It sounds like nonsense to me -- is it idiomatic in some region?

i tried to translate in my mind and sometimes it leads to some mistakes (due to wrong word choosing or etc)in my sentences.What i wanted to say is ''of and about is used to express our feelings with nouns after adjectives and because my language is agglutanitive language,i didn't understand why of and about is used and what differentiate them between.

In the simplest terms possible, 'of' shows possession or relationship while 'about' indicates a topic or subject.
Using a couple of your examples, we would say "I am angry about your decisions" because "about" relates the emotion of anger to the reason for it (the decisions).
We would say "she is scared of flying" to indicate a general fear of flying because "of" links the fear to its source or cause. However, we might say "she is scared about flying" if the "flying" referred to a specific upcoming flight, because the flight itself may not be the reason for it and there may be some other cause of the fear related to the timing, the destination, or something else.

thanks for answering.So i can say that ''of'' includes the source of our feelings like scary,amaze,suprize etc..When we use it with of, i should understand just what is scarcing this person ( why or other reasons are not answered) .When i use ''about'',i should understand, reasons causing this feeling.
